# Sequence of effects for jQuery clickable element

Tags: jquery

I styled an h2 tag, and using jQuery turned it into a button of sorts. When clicked, hidden content will slide down from underneath this button. My problem is the sequence of effects, I can't get them timed right.

Here is how I'd like it to look:

1. The button has rounded corners. When clicked, the rounded corners on the on the bottom are removed so it looks like the hidden content is sliding out of the bottom of the button.
2. When the button is clicked again, the content slides up into the button. When the content has finished sliding up, the button resumes its appearance of all rounded corners.

On my [jfiddle mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrmy/WsE8R/4/) there are 2 example buttons. Example 1 works with the first click, but the button becomes round before the content has slid back up when clicked again.

When clicking Example2 the button stays round as the content slides out. But when clicked again to hide the content, the sequence works in the correct order.

Here's the gist:

```
$('.section').hide();


$('.example1').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow')
    .prev().toggleClass('open-header');    
});


$('.example2').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).next()
        .slideToggle('slow')
        .queue( function(next) {
            $(this).prev().toggleClass('open-header');
            $(this).dequeue();
        }); 
});
```

I want to combine the working parts of each button but I'm not sure how. I read other posts about using .queue() or callbacks, but I must not know what I'm doing cuz I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to use [jQueryUI's Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible).

Comment: Thanks, Dom, that is nice suggestion. I'll look into that. But I'd also like to know for my own education how I can get my example to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using toggle, just check if it has the `.open-header` class manually, and when sliding up, remove the class on the callback:

```
$('.example1').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open-header')) {
      $(this).addClass('open-header');
        $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp('slow',function() {
           $(this).siblings('h2').removeClass('open-header');
        });

    }
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WsE8R/5/

Comment: kennypu, That created the effect I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to detect the existence of the `open-header` class in the function and change the order of operations.  You need the class toggle first on open and you need it last on close.

So something like this:

```
$('.example1').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('open-header')) {
        // we need to close it
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow').prev().toggleClass('open_header');
    } else {
        // we need to open it
        $(this).toggleClass('open_header').next().slideToggle('slow');
    }   
});
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the input. I played around with this but got the same results -- parts of the animation played simultaneously instead of sequentially.